# Parse.com Send auto push notification on new data

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, tableview

I have an App that synch data from parse.
I have a class and object.
When i added new data (row) i need that parse send auto push notification to all device that have the app installed.
I try to read the doc but not but can figure out how to do it.
Any help?

Comment: Willing to share some code with us?  That would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand from your explanation, you want to send push notification to all device  when a new row is inserted. To do this, you can use Parse Cloud function and trigger this function when a new row is inserted. Another way (it is not clear from your explanation), you can use Parse Cloud afterSave function. When a new  row is inserted to a class, afterSave function is triggered by Parse. So you can send  Push notification in afterSave function. Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: YES! thats what i mean.. New row and push to devices. Im going to try ur solution to afterSave. Tnx.

Comment: Nice, one suggestion, to send Push to all device you should query the Installation table and give the query result as input to push. Regards

Comment: Cant set the cloudCode. Get error in terminal when i put the install code line "curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash"                                                        /bin/bash: line 1: html: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
'bin/bash: line 2: `<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>

Comment: Try again and first read the tutorial. Parse tutorials are good starting point. Hope this helps.Regards.